# Tensorflow Lite export looks like it do not add weigths and add unsupported operations

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I want to reload some of my model variables with the saved weight in the chheckpoint and then export it to the tflite file.

The question is a bit tricky without see code, so I made this Colab jupyter notebook with the complete code to explain it better (All code is working, you can actually copy in a new collab and change if you want):

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1wSor4CxEz36LgElVi4y_N8uiSt4-j9b2#scrollTo=XKBQzoW_wd4A

I got it working but with two issues:

- **The exported .tflite file is like 3Ks**, so I do not believe it is the entire model with the weights in it. Only the input is an image of 128x128x3, one weight for each is more than 3K.
- When I finally import the model **in Android, I have this error**: "Didn't find custom op for name 'VariableV2' /n Didn't find custom op for name 'ReorderAxes' /n  Registration failed."

Maybe the last error is cause the save/restore operations? They look like are there when I save the graph definition.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I realize my problem.. I'm trying to convert to TFLITE a model without previously freezing it, TFLITE do not allow "VariableV2" nodes cause they should not be there..

All the problem is corrected freezing the model like this:

```
output_graph_def = graph_util.convert_variables_to_constants(sess, sess.graph.as_graph_def(), ["output"])
```

I lost some time looking for that, hope it helps.

Comment: Could you share your code or command for converting pb to tflite? Thanks a lot!